# How do I make results available from ipc call available outside a function?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have two functions. One that makes a call to ipcmain and one that is parent to that function. The ipcmain call gets some data from the database and returns it. The idea is to have these calls organized within a service.

My issue is something is not firing correctly and I am not sure where my issue is.

If I console log the result, it correctly logs, however, the log from the parent calls first and logs the EventEmitter Object.

How can I get these to fire in order and the results from the call to ipcmain availabe outside this function?

I have already tried assigning the results to a variable at the top of the function and then returning that after the call, however, the results are exactly the same.

I have also tried converting both functions to async await with no results.

My hunch is that the "backend" ipcmain.on() function is not sending a promise and therefore the parent log is occurring before the value is set.

```
// Parent Function
async getDbs (event){
  var databaseName = event.target.parentNode.innerText;
  this.selectedServer = this.LocalStorage.getItem(databaseName);
  this.databaseArray = await this.BackendService.getDbs(this.selectedServer)
  console.log(await this.databaseArray)
}
```

```
// Call to IPC Main
getDbs(config) {
  window.ipc.send('auth-getdbs', config);
  return window.ipc.on('auth-getdbs-reply', async (event, result) => {
    // Correctly logs an array of databases
    console.log(result);
    // returns the EventEmitter object
    return result;
  });
}
```

```
// IPC Main Function
ipcMain.on('auth-getdbs', async (event, arg) => {
  var results = await handlers.getDbs(event, arg, scope);
  event.sender.send('auth-getdbs-reply', results);
})
```

Expected Results:
Both console logs output the array of database names

Actual Results:
Parent function console logs EventEmitter and the console log from ipcmain call logs the array of databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem you have is what you think the method returns. In your function `getDbs`, I'm really not sure that the method `window.ipc.on` returns what is returned by the callback; it is returning the EventEmitter created by the method.

Since it seems that you are working with an async callback, what I would do is something like this.

```
// Call to IPC Main
getDbs(config) {
  window.ipc.send('auth-getdbs', config);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.ipc.on('auth-getdbs-reply', (event, result) => {
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```

The function would return a Promise which resolves to the result you are expecting to be returned. The way you call this function, since you are using the `await` keyword, should stay the same.